# Ionic 2 : EXCEPTION: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: ionic2

I want to send data to my database and when i click on submit button, i get this exeption : **EXCEPTION: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

I really dont know what to do :/ you can check my code on my github: https://github.com/majlo23/makeorder-ionic
and here is my PHP code: https://github.com/dmikulasova/make-order_server

Comment: Please provide code snippets instead of showing list of files.

Comment: you will need to narrow it down.. I suggest you test your server side api using a rest client like postman or advanced rest client. Json output you are `echo`ing clearly is malformed..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but when i changed the serve response format to JSON, it worked for me.

**More details**

**Node example:**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "success"
  });
});
```

**Ionic 2**

I generated a service.ts file to define my HTTP request method to be shared with all components.

I defined function load that return an Observable

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
import {BackendURL} from '../utils/backendURL';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  load() {
    return this.http.get(BackendURL.host).map((res:Response) => res.json()).catch(BackendURL.handleError);
  }

}
```

In my component, i inject the service and i subscribe to the observable.Now you should see the response logged in the console.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {HomeService} from '../../services/home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public hs:HomeService) {
    console.log('constructor HomePage');
    this.hs.load().subscribe((data:any) => console.log('constructor  HomePage data',data));
  } 
 }
```